# How to fetch all records using SQL query using JOIN command (related to Distinct)

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL Query

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) as recommendations_vote_average

FROM tmdb_movies 

LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=155

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

This is how my recommentions able looks like: [image]

So, now `,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) as recommendations_vote_average`
 If I use `DISTINCT` here, then it do not show vote_average of the following movies: `The Matrix, Inception, Iron Man 2, Captain America: The First Avenger`. +it shows wrong `vote_average` of all movies (leaving first)

If i do not use `Distinct` then it shows 7.5 in all records.

How to solve this problem? Let me know, if you need more information.

Comment: Is `recommendations_vote_average` is average? and why you are using `group_concat`?

Comment: No, it is not. I am using group_concat to echo them together

Answer (score 0):

If you need the average recommendation, you can use the AVG aggregate function:

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,AVG( recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) as recommendations_vote_average
FROM tmdb_movies 
LEFT JOIN recommendations ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=155
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
        SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(recommendations.recommendations_vote_average) 
         as recommendations_vote_average
        FROM tmdb_movies 
        LEFT JOIN (select * from recommendations group by recommendations_vote_average) 
        recommendations 
        ON recommendations.recommendations_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id 
        Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=155
        GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'DBnamehere.recommendations.recommendationsid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: check the query in phpmyadmin

Comment: `#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbnamehere.recommendations.recommendationsid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
`

Comment: can you feet you your tables on sqlfiddle so i can check where?
I can provide you solution b'coz also facing same issue.